# Crossfilter 1.4.8 with more than 32 dimension, group all not removing correctly during filter the 32nd dimension

Tags: crossfilter

With crossfilter 1.4.8, i have more than 32 dimension, and group each dimension. At first time, i call
32nd dimension's filterExact and the call other dimension's group `all()`, the group value is correct. But when I remove filter and call 32nd dimension's `filterExact` function again, i found that the less than 32nd dimession's group not removing value corrently, but the large than dimession's group removing value corrently.

Here is my demo: [Demo URL](https://jsfiddle.net/5b1dtkov/8/)

Through debugging, it is found that when the onlyExcept function of array.js is called for verification when the value is removed, it always returns false. As shown in the picture: [image]

Am hoping someone can suggest places to inspect either my code or the crossfilter code to find the problem.

Comment: Sorry I haven’t found time to look at this yet. Sounds like it is probably a bug. We just fixed a very similar bug on dimension #32. Would you be willing to open an issue on [crossfilter/crossfilter](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter) and supply a test case?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and I have opened an issue to describe this, here is the issue link: [issue url](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/issues/158) @Gordon